# Logical or every entry in two arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, logic, addition

Say I have these

```
a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I want something like `c = a | b`
and get the answer as `c = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". Your question doesn't show any research or effort, which is needs to do. As is it's like you're fishing for an answer, which isn't what Stack Overflow is about. Please tell us where you've searched for answers and why those didn't work for you, or show us what you've tried writing and explain the error.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] 
b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

a.zip(b).map { |a, b| a | b }
#=> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing bit-twiddling with an integer's bits the elements of an array, which is a rather roundabout way of doing that. I suggest you simply deal with the integers directly:

```
x = 8
y = 2
```

Note:

```
x.to_s(2) #=> "1000"
y.to_s(2) #=> "10"
```

or, say,

```
x.to_s(2).rjust(8,"0") #=> "00001000"
y.to_s(2).rjust(8,"0") #=> "00000010"
```

Now you can obtain the result you want very simply with [Fixnum#|](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C):

```
z = x | y #=> 10
```

Let's confirm:

```
z.to_s(2) #=> "1010"
```

To retrieve bit `i` (`i=1`), use [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
y[0]  #=> 0
y[1]  #=> 1
y[2]  #=> 0
y[99] #=> 0
```

To set bit i, you will need to use [Fixnum#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3CCC) to obtain an integer that has a `1` in bit position `i` and `0` for all other bit positions:

```
1 << i
```

For example:

```
1 << O #=> 1
1 << 1 #=> 2
1 << 2 #=> 4
```

Alternatively, you could of course write:

```
2**i
```

To set bit `i` to `0` use [Fixnum#^](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5E) (pronounced "XOR"). For `i=1`,

```
y = y ^ (1<<1) #=> 0
```

which we can more compactly as:

```
y ^= (1<<1)
```

To set bit `i` to `1`, for `i=1`, (recall `y` is now `0`):

```
y |= (1<<1) #=> 2
```

Similarly (`y` now equals `2`),

```
y |= (1<<9) #=> 514
y.to_s(2)   #=> "1000000010"
```

Comment: Great answer. +1; Pretty much what I would've said.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert you arrays to numbers and then just use the binary operators, it should be faster if you need to perform lots of such operations.
If needed you can convert the result back to array.

```
a = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

a_number = a.join.to_i(2)
b_number = b.join.to_i(2)

c_number = a_number | b_number

c_array = c_number.to_s(2).split('').map(&:to_i)
c_array = [0] * (a.size - c_array.size) + c_array if c_array.size < a.size

p c_number.to_s(2)
p c_array
```